# getting size of multiple files located inside the hard disk using python

Tags: python

This question is about getting size of multiple files located inside the hard disk. 
The code has been improved based on the answers here:

```
import os, glob
with open ('file_size.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    files= glob.glob ('*.jpg')
    for file in files:
        get_sizes = os.path.getsize (file)
        for item in get_sizes:
            if item < 1000:
                size = str (item) + 'K'
            else:
                size = str (round ((item/(1024*1024)),1)) + 'M'
            file_name = os.path.basename (file)
            outfile.write(file_name + ' ' + size + '\n')
```

However the above code still produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\test\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    for item in get_sizes:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Post the code you are using. The code you showed here has syntactic errors, and it would also trigger `NameError`s and `TypeError`s when fixed. Assuming your real code has all these things fixed, the problem is probably that the second `if`(`if item > 1000`) is indented too much when it should be at the same level of the `if item < 1000`

Comment: i have edited for the errors you have mentioned@Bakuriu

Comment: Edited my answer to account for this error also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're struggling with nesting if statements.  Everything after the first `if` will not execute unless the item's small enough, and if you get that far, nothing after the second `if` will execute.

I'm assuming you'd like to set `size` to something different based on how big the file is and then ALWAYS output a line to your output file.  Unindenting will do that.  I've also changed your second `if` to an `else` so that one or the other always executes.

Also, os.path.getsize() only returns the size for one file, so you don't need to loop over the result.

```
import os, glob
with open ("file_size.txt", "w") as outfile:
    files= glob.glob ("G:\\*.jpg")
    for file in files:
        get_size = os.path.getsize (file)
        if get_size < 1000:
            size = str (item) + 'K'
        else:
            size = str (round ((item/(1024*1024)),1)) + 'M'
        out_name = os.path.basename (file)
        outfile.write(out_file + " " + size + "\n")
```

This takes the assignment to `out_name` and the write to `outfile` outside your `if` statements so that they always execute, rather than being dependent on the `if` conditions.

Comment: thanks, but still does not work. i have edited the question Mark R. Wilkins

Comment: Updated to fix.  I was wondering why you were looping over the result from `os.path.getsize()`!

Answer (score 1):

```
if item < 1000:
            size = str (item) + 'K'
            if item > 1000:
                #this will never execute
                #since you have already asserted that item < 1000
```